# Ember destructing function

Tags: ecmascript-6

I see often come across code in Ember.js that use object destructing to retrieve a function

```
const { computed } = Ember;
```

If there is advantage to this pattern instead of calling `Ember.computed` directly other than reduce the code? Would this go against encapsulating functions in objects?

Comment: It's merely a coding style. Semantically it's identical. It might be marginally easier to port such code to the new module structure of Ember. It has nothing to do with "encapsulation".

Comment: What you mean by this "It might be marginally easier to port such code to the new module structure of Ember."? By encapsulation I mean what happens if you adding new js libary and they computed function define globally would that break the code

Comment: I don't see how anything defined globally could clobber this, unless `Ember` was re-defined, at which point all bets are off anyway, and in any case in practice the code you show would be preceded by `import Ember from 'ember';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from having to write only `computed` instead of `Ember.computed` every time (which admittedly pays off only for many usages), the main advantage is that `computed` becomes a *local* and `const` variable. This can speed up the variable lookup time in tight spots, not needing to search the global scope for `Ember`. It also prevents someone from messing with your code by overwriting `Ember.computed` afterwards, depending on where exactly in your module the destructuring is done.

Comment: Well, the code shown would inevitably be preceded by `import Ember from 'ember';`, so there would be no search of the global scope. In any case, `Ember.computed` is used in property declarations, which are parsed at "compile" time, and would never occur in a "tight spot". If any of these reasons were compelling, one would expect many/most applications to adopt this approach, but IRL everyone uses `Ember.computed`.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, that's true, my answer was not ember-specific. A framework should probably use named exports for such commonly used functions, so that you could do `import { computed } from 'ember';`

Comment: In fact there is a plan to restructure Ember modules/imports in the way you mention in your comment, which is either already in place or will be soon, so you would would write `import { computed } from 'ember/core';` or something equivalent.